# Xml is not defined when passed using ajax request

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, rest

I am passing xml on my ajax request. i have this:

```
var xml = $.json2xml(invoiceGroup, options);
```

It's a json to xml conversion and this code for the ajax side

```
$.ajax({
        url: devUrl + servEntity + 'createinvoice/',
        data: xml,
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: 'xml',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        ProcessData:false,
        success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
                invoiceSuccess(msg);      
        },
        error: function(error){
              console.log(error);      
        } 
    });
```

What am i doing wrong? when proceed firebug displays "xml is not defined" any ideas?

Comment: If Firebug tells you "xml is not defined" then most probably xml is not defined :-) Seriously, where did you define xml? Global scope? Local to a function? Where is the $.ajax() call located relative to the scope of "xml"? Is $.json2xml() working asynchronously by any chance?

Comment: i defined it local to a function. thanks for that. but still my ajax doesnt work..

Comment: yes $.json2xml works. i tested it first by printing its result and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataType` option is actually the data type of the *response*, not the *request*.  You'll need to alter that value to whatever type of data your server is responding with.  It looks like it's possibly `html` or `text`, but I can't tell from what info you've provided.

Comment: changed it back to json. Since i am expecting json.